# What's another way to say "problem area"?

Tags: synonyms, technical, computing, professions

Looking for some powerful, formal words with a slight negative connotation for a resume/performance assessment. The general context pertains to computer software development.

These aren't *my* problem areas, they are areas that were problems in someone else's work that I have identified (thus saving the day).

Here's the actual context:

> Regularly conducted memory audits to identify problem areas

Comment: It's not clear what problem you have with the term "problem areas". You've mentioned in another comment that you problem is with the use of "areas" / locality but haven't explained why. Nor have you explained the overall context. I assume (from the reference to 'memory audits') that you are discussing computers?

Comment: Yeah, sorry.

This is with respect to computers/technology. I don't mind the term problem area, but I end up using it a lot. Looking for variants that have the same feeling.

Comment: Of course, you could just say "to identify problems." (omit " area").

Comment: What @TrevorD said. If "areas" is an important word here I think it needs to be retained. That's to say if the purpose of the memory audits is to identify *areas where [multiple] problems occur*, I don't see how OP's original can be improved on. If it's actually supposed to identify *individual problems*, just discard that pointless extra word.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @convoke.  Your use of tags can help those who are watching them for their areas of specialty.  Enjoy!

Comment: If the "problem areas" you're talking about are in the software being developed (and not in the employee's work performance), you could vary your word choice by occasionally replacing "problem areas" with "trouble spots" or "vulnerabilities."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regularly conducted memory audits to identify opportunities for improvement.
Regularly conducted memory audits to identify issues that needed to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

***deficiencies***

***failings***

***shortcomings***

***weaknesses***

***flaws***

Following your comments, if I get the drift I would propose* **chink in armour**. Alternatively ***weak area***,***weak spot*** or ***blind spot***are perfectly acceptable expressions.

Comment: Not bad... but those are mostly just covering the "problem" half of things.

A problem **area** is different than a problem, in my mind at least; the locality is important.

Comment: Perhaps adding *domains* to the above problem identifiers, such as *domains of deficits*. A more esoteric verson could use *locus* or *loci* (Latin for *place* and *places*), as in *loci of weaknesses*.

Comment: @convoke please see the updated answer in response to your comments

Comment: Thanks user. *Chink in armour* is too informal. *Weak area* is too similar to *problem area*; I'm trying to avoid doubling up on any of the words.

*Weak spot* works, but doesn't feel powerful enough. Spot doesn't really have a strong connotation.

Comment: I have a feeling you will like my last suggestion - blind spot

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a qualifier on the term *technical debt*, such as

> Unidentified Technical Debt

This will use a term common to management, "technical debt", while also casting it in one of the most dangerous lights, *misidentification*.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I had to talk to parents about their children's progress in English I tried to be tactful but also honest. There are ways to soften the blow and be supportive at the same time. I hope these phrases are of help.

E.g. *Computer software development is* [name of employee] **Achilles' heel**.

*(... software...) is his* **main/principal weakness**.

*(His ...) is* **in need of improvement/requires further attention**.

(His ...) is **inconsistent/unremarkable**.

(His skills in ...) have been (until now) **unsatisfactory/flawed/limited**.

[Name of employee] **needs to focus** on .....

**P.S**: I may have completely misinterpreted the OP's question. If that is the case, if he would be so kind as to inform me and I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Grey areas", "Snags", "areas for improvement", but all these depend on the context in which you intend to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I use, with tongue planted firmly in cheek, **suboptimal**